# Already built exception with springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to build and application that uses Spring security but getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
```

I have no idea what can cause it. Below you can see the configs:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration {

// This first section of the configuration just makes sure that Spring Security picks
// up the UserDetailsService that we create below. 
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    protected void registerAuthentication(
            final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}

/**
 *  This method is used to configure who is allowed to access which parts of our
 *  resource server (i.e. the "/video" endpoint) 
 */
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServer extends
        ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIDEO_ID = "video";

    // This method configures the OAuth scopes required by clients to access
    // all of the paths in the video service.
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();

        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").anonymous();


        // If you were going to reuse this class in another
        // application, this is one of the key sections that you
        // would want to change

        // Require all GET requests to have client "read" scope
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
            .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");

        // Require all other requests to have "write" scope
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
         resources.resourceId(VIDEO_ID);
    }

}

/**
 * This class is used to configure how our authorization server (the "/oauth/token" endpoint) 
 * validates client credentials.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 100)
protected static class OAuth2Config extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // Delegate the processing of Authentication requests to the framework
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    // A data structure used to store both a ClientDetailsService and a UserDetailsService
    private ClientAndUserDetailsService combinedService_;

    /**
     * 
     * This constructor is used to setup the clients and users that will be able to login to the
     * system. This is a VERY insecure setup that is using hard-coded lists of clients / users /
     * passwords and should never be used for anything other than local testing
     * on a machine that is not accessible via the Internet. Even if you use
     * this code for testing, at the bare minimum, you should consider changing the
     * passwords listed below and updating the VideoSvcClientApiTest.
     * 
     * @param auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public OAuth2Config() throws Exception {

        // If you were going to reuse this class in another
        // application, this is one of the key sections that you
        // would want to change


        // Create a service that has the credentials for all our clients
        ClientDetailsService csvc = new InMemoryClientDetailsServiceBuilder()
                // Create a client that has "read" and "write" access to the
                // video service
                .withClient("mobile").authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read","write").resourceIds("video")
                .and()
                // Create a second client that only has "read" access to the
                // video service
                .withClient("mobileReader").authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read").resourceIds("video")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600).and().build();

        // Create a series of hard-coded users. 
        UserDetailsService svc = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                Arrays.asList(
                        User.create("admin", "pass", "ADMIN", "USER"),
                        User.create("user0", "pass", "USER"),
                        User.create("user1", "pass", "USER"),
                        User.create("user2", "pass", "USER"),
                        User.create("user3", "pass", "USER"),
                        User.create("user4", "pass", "USER"),
                        User.create("user5", "pass", "USER")));

        // Since clients have to use BASIC authentication with the client's id/secret,
        // when sending a request for a password grant, we make each client a user
        // as well. When the BASIC authentication information is pulled from the
        // request, this combined UserDetailsService will authenticate that the
        // client is a valid "user". 
        combinedService_ = new ClientAndUserDetailsService(csvc, svc);
    }

    /**
     * Return the list of trusted client information to anyone who asks for it.
     */
    @Bean
    public ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService() throws Exception {
        return combinedService_;
    }

    /**
     * Return all of our user information to anyone in the framework who requests it.
     */
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return combinedService_;
    }

    /**
     * This method tells our AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter to use the delegated AuthenticationManager
     * to process authentication requests.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    /**
     * This method tells the AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter to use our self-defined client details service to
     * authenticate clients with.
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Remove your first `@Configuration` on `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration`. BTW: It would help, if you format your code with proper intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the annotations or build objects is triggering the security context to get built twice.

Try removing @EnableWebSecurity annotation from the SecurityConfig class. SpringBoot is probably injecting that for you automatically behind the scenes.

If that doesn't work try commenting out the `.build()` call (or the whole object) on the `ClientDetailsService`. If something in that chain creates a security context it could cause that issue.

Comment: I have removed @EnableWebSecurity but not solve the issue. I can remove ClientDetailsService csvc object (where the build is) but I need it, how to do?

Comment: I would just try it first to see if it works. It might not. However, if that solves the problem then you'll need to dig into that code to figure out where in the chain it is re-initializing the security context.

Comment: I have switched to jdk8 and now works. I do not know why !

Comment: @StefanoMaglione What JDK did you use before?

Comment: I have used jdk11